# can i use stripe checkout with destination charges?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm wondering if there is any way to charge some kind of fee on transactions using the new Stripe Checkout system. In this particular instance I am using Laravel 8 with Livewire. In my component I have a function tied to a button called setStripeSession.

```
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
              'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'product_data' => [
                  'name' => 'Custom Media',
                ],
                'unit_amount' => $this->toPennies($price),
              ],
              'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'http://e68ec3e6b8b2.ngrok.io/',
            'cancel_url' => 'http://e68ec3e6b8b2.ngrok.io/',
            ],['stripe_account_id'=>$this->stripe_account_id]);
            $this->stripe_session_id = $session->id;
            Message::where('id',$message_id)->update(['stripe_session_id'=>$this->stripe_session_id ]);
            $this->emit('PayonStripe',['ssid'=>$session->id]);

    }
```

I imagined adding something like the below code but the variables are not recognized by the stripe API during the rquest.

```
  'transfer_data' => [
    'destination' => '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes! You can set these within the [`payment_intent_data` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data):

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [...],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => 'http://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'http://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_intent_data' => [
    'application_fee_amount' => 100, // optional
    'transfer_data' => [
      'destination' => 'acct_123',
    ],
  ],
]);
```

A number of parameters are exposed this way in Checkout, such as `metadata` for the payment intent and similar data for subscription mode under `subscription_data`.